# Show that completely regular is a topological property

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Show that [completely regular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyRegularSpace.html) is a topological property.

> Let $ X $ be a completely regular space and let $ h:X \rightarrow Y $ a homeomorphism. We will prove that $ Y $ is completely regular.

**My Attempt**

Suppose that $ C $ is a closed subset of $ Y $ and that $ y \in Y \setminus C $ is an arbitrary point. Then, there exists $ x \in X $ such that $ h(x) = y $ and $ x \not\in h^{-1}(C) $. Since $ h $ is continuous, $ h^{-1}(C) $ is closed in $ X $.

Since $ X $ is completely regular, there is a continuous function $ f $ such that $ f(x) = f(h^{-1}(y)) = 0 $ and $ f(h^{-1}(C)) = 1 $. Thus, $ Y $ is completely regular.

I'm not sure of the proof, mainly of the last two lines.

Comment: You can say that $x = h^{-1}(y)$, not just "there exists $x$," but that's just an issue of style. The proof is logically solid. What you're doing is just saying that $f \circ h^{-1}$ is the required function on $Y$, which is exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $Y$ is completely regular, you need to prove there exists a continuous function $g:Y\to [0,1]$ such such that $g(y)=0$ and $g(c)=1$ for all $c\in C$.  You haven't actually exhibited such a function, so you haven't proved that $Y$ is completely regular.  However, you've done most of the work needed to do so.  Based on what you have, what could you define $g$ as?

Comment: Where is it used that $ h $ is a homeomorphism? Here $ x = h^{-1}(y) $?

Comment: Well, in what you've written, you haven't used that yet (only that $h$ is a continuous surjection).  But have you tried defining a function $g$ as I suggested yet?